# Equations not showing

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}

 f(x) = x^2

\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

When I type this in MikTex I always get an error and cannot see the Typeset. Why?
I always get this
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You must have ***no*** blank line in the `equation*` environment (and in all other math environments).